# Script stops if anything is Echo'd

Tags: php

I have an unusual problem which i have not come up against before .

Basically I am trying to stop the page  request but continue executing the code. The code below worked fine on local testing however when uploaded to the server anything that is Echo'd after the ob flush and flush basically kills the script.

If I comment out all the echo's the script runs fine .

```
ob_end_clean();
header("Connection: close");
ignore_user_abort(true);
ob_start();
echo 'Text the user will see';
$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size");
ob_end_flush(); // All output buffers must be flushed here
flush();        // Force output to client
// Do processing here 
sleep(30);
echo('Text user will never see');
```

I don't understand how the echo after the flush causes the script to terminate.

Help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you wait 30 seconds?

Comment: Yes , but for some reason the script just doesn't run if an echo is present after the ob flush

Comment: Unless there's a typo that's causing a parse error, that's impossible. Check your PHP error log.

Comment: There is no parse error, PHP error log has no errors. Literally all I have to do to make the script run is comment out the echo.

Comment: When you have the second echo, they don't see the first echo either?

Comment: First echo works , just anything after the 2nd echo doesn't like the script ends on the second echo

Comment: Try adding another `flush()` at the end.

Comment: Honestly I'm not too concerned about the 2nd echo not being displayed . I'm more concerned that the rest of the script stops functioning . This same script was working fine on another server .

Comment: I still can't think of any reason why that echo statement would have any effect on the rest of the script. What does the rest of the script do?

Comment: Rest of the script updates some data in the DB .I am also stumped as to why an echo stops the script just because it's after a flush .